# OpenCV 3 / Neural Networks / error in predict / Ptr< ANN_MLP > / C++

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, opencv3.0

I'm trying to implement simple a neural network example in OpenCV version 3.0.0. According to [latest reference](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d0/dce/classcv_1_1ml_1_1ANN__MLP.html). To make things simple, I use random 15 examples from [iris data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) for training. I have also reduced the output species to 2, just to make things much more simpler.

where trainData, and trainLabels are declared as:

```
Mat trainData(15, 4, CV_32FC1); //15 examples with 4 features each
Mat trainLabels(15, 1, CV_32FC1);
```

trainData:

```
[5.5, 3.5, 1.3, 0.2;
 6.5, 2.8, 4.5999999, 1.5;
 6.3000002, 2.3, 4.4000001, 1.3;
 6, 2.2, 4, 1;
 4.5999999, 3.0999999, 1.5, 0.2;
 5, 3.2, 1.2, 0.2;
 7.4000001, 2.8, 6.0999999, 1.9;
 6, 2.9000001, 4.5, 1.5;
 5, 3.4000001, 1.5, 0.2;
 6.4000001, 2.9000001, 4.3000002, 1.3;
 7.1999998, 3.5999999, 6.0999999, 2.5;
 5.0999999, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5;
 7.1999998, 3, 5.8000002, 1.6;
 6.0999999, 2.8, 4, 1.3;
 5.8000002, 2.7, 4.0999999, 1]
```

trainLabels:

```
[0;
 0;
 0;
 0;
 0;
 0;
 1;
 0;
 0;
 0;
 1;
 0;
 1;
 0;
 0]
```

The neural network code compiles and run without error up to predict. Here is the sniplet:

```
Ptr< ANN_MLP >  nn = ANN_MLP::create();
nn->setActivationFunction(cv::ml::ANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM);
nn->setTrainMethod(cv::ml::ANN_MLP::BACKPROP);
nn->setBackpropMomentumScale(0.1);
nn->setBackpropWeightScale(0.1);
nn->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, (int)100000, 1e-6));

//setting the NN layer size
cv :: Mat layers = cv :: Mat (4 , 1 , CV_32SC1 );
layers . row (0) = cv :: Scalar (4) ;
layers . row (1) = cv :: Scalar (4) ;
layers . row (2) = cv :: Scalar (4) ;
layers . row (3) = cv :: Scalar (1) ;
nn->setLayerSizes(layers);
nn->train(trainData, ROW_SAMPLE, trainLabels);
```

But whenever I try to do "predict", I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error :

```
nn->predict(trainData.row(1));
```

What is the problem here, and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For reference in Python, I use:  trainData.**getTestResponses**(), where trainData is the entire struct of my input data.

I hope this helps...OpenCV 3's new structure confused me at first, but I appreciate the methods in which things are done now.

Comment: Its equivalent in C++ is "virtual Mat cv::ml::TrainData::getTestResponses ( ) const" , and it is returning the "original" response values of the test data. I had previously (mistakenly) marked this post as correct answer but just realized that "getTestResponses()" has nothing to with prediction.

Comment: I actually agree.  I haven't successfully trained and gotten proper output with any OpenCV 3's NN training...

Comment: Since I can't get a solution neither, I'm using Theano on Python these days. It has a very good documentation, and quite flexible.

Comment: Same!  There is a tricky point with it:  debugging!  Since you are given dummy names, like Node 29, and it same it has a dimension mismatch, you cannot locate it by looking at your network.  I ran into this just recently.

Answer (score -1):

Try to switch the order of the `setActivationFunction()` and `setLayerSize()` functions. You should call the `setLayerSize()` before `setAtctivationFunction()`. It was the solution in my case (OpenCV 3.1).